# Texture is black when manually building mipmap

Tags: opengl, textures, mipmaps

I am trying to manually build a mipmap from a series of images. For the sake of brevity, let's assume the file containing the images I want (from 256x256 to 32x32) have paths `file_1...4`.

What I do to load the texture is:

```
GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1,&textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 4);

for i from 1 to 4
    unsigned char* image =  stbi_load_from_file(file_i, &width, &height, &comp, 3);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (i-1), GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    stbi_free_image(image);
```

When I go and try to use this created texture in a render all I got is a black result. Using singularly each texture works properly, so I excluded they're malformed. What can it be?

Comment: You have 4 mip-levels, correct? From 0 to 3. If yes, then `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` should be 3, not 4.

Comment: Oh my what a stupid error I did, thank you @glampert !

Comment: Ok, I'll post an "official" answer then ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only apparent error in your code is that you seem to specifying 4 mip-levels, from level 0 to level 3, however, you set `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` to 4. The max level is the zero-based index of the last mip-level, so in this case, it should be 3:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 3);
```

Comment: Per documentation the default value for this is 1000, which suggests that values too high just get silently clamped.  It's shouldn't be normally required to set this unless you're not loading a full mipmap chain.  https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexParameter.xhtml